# SettingWitchCopyWarning Pandas using .ix

Tags: python, loops, pandas, warnings

I am looping through my dataframe using all samples but one in order to make a prediction for the one left out, which I want to do for all samples (I have a small dataset.

The loop I am currently using is the following.

```
   for i in range(0, length_df): 
         np.delete(indices, i)
         baseline.fit(df.ix[indices, feature_labels], df.ix[indices, label_to_predict])
         df.ix[i,'prediction'] = baseline.predict(df.ix[left_out_index, feature_labels])
         np.add(indices,i)
```

I am getting the following two warnings from Pandas:

```
DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 
and willraise ValueError in 0.19. 
Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a 
single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample. 
DeprecationWarning)

SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I thought using .ix() made sure one doesn't make incorrect copies. Should I ignore these warnings? And a related question, is there perhaps a more efficient way to do this in Pandas?

**Note**: As of Pandas v0.20, `.ix` [indexer is deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-ix) in favour of `.iloc` / `.loc`.

Comment: Note that the first warning is not coming from pandas, but from sklearn. Further, are you sure the SettingWithCopyWarning comes from that code snippet? As you are not setting any values there.

Comment: Also, it looks like you are doing some kind of cross validation with left out records. In that case you may want to look at the cross validation methods in sklearn: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html

Comment: I edited my post, as I do assign values, now that is more clear.
I know about the module, but as I would like an explicit output, I implemented it myself.

Comment: How is `df` created and adapted before these steps? Because that is what will cause the warning. You can always do `df = df.copy()` just before the loop to prevent the warning.

Comment: `df` is a split from a datafile that has been read-in by pandas. I tried the suggestion, but still the same error. I don't think that any harm is done, but I'm still wondering what would be the 'right' to implement this.